# Polyline change dinamically in Google Maps according to a Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, combobox

I'm trying to charge differents paths in a google maps acordding to the selection of a Combobox but it isn't working , i used an if but in this way the map doesn't charge the polyline. 
This is the HTML Code :

```
<body>


    <section id="mapa">
    </section>

    <section id="formulario">
        <form action="index.html" id="seleccion">
        <select name="Continente" id="continente" >
        <option value="">--Selecciona--</option>
        <option value="NorteAmerica">Norte America</option>
        <option value="CentroAmerica">Centroamerica</option>
        <option value="SurAmerica">Suramerica</option>
        <option value="Europa">Europa</option>
        <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
        <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    </select>

    <select name="pagina" id="pagina">
        <option value="">--Selecciona--</option>
        <option value="Google">Google</option>
        <option value="Youtube">Youtube</option>
        <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="Wikipedia">Wikipedia</option>
        <option value="Baidu">Baidu</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Hacer Traceroute" id="boton"/>
</form>
</section>
```

Javascript is here :

```
var traza = [];
var facebookNorteAmerica1 = [
  {lat:37.7749 , lng:-122.4194},
  {lat:40.7199 , lng:-74.0050},
  {lat:37.4419 , lng:-122.1430},
  {lat:37.4419 , lng:-122.1430},
  {lat:37.3394 , lng:-121.8950},
  {lat:37.3394 , lng:-121.8950},
  {lat:37.3394 , lng:-121.8950}
  ];

var baiduNorteAmerica1 = [
  {lat:37.7749 , lng:-122.4194},
  {lat:40.7199 , lng:-74.0050},
  {lat:37.7749 , lng:-122.4194},
  {lat:37.3394 , lng:-121.8950},
  {lat:37.3394 , lng:-121.8950},
  {lat:41.8558 , lng:123.9233},
  {lat:39.9075 , lng:116.3972},
  {lat:39.9075 , lng:116.3972},
  {lat:34.7725 , lng:113.7266},
  {lat:23.1167 , lng:113.2500}
  ];

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
});

$("#boton").click(function(){
  var continente = $("#continente").val();
  var pagina = $("#pagina").val();

  if (continente == "Norte America" && pagina=="Baidu") {
    traza = baiduNorteAmerica1;
  }else{
    traza = facebookNorteAmerica1;
  }
});

 var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path:traza,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#4800ff',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1
    });



  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

I know that probably the error is the jquery because continente and pagina initially are " " , but i sincerely don't know how to get those values when i click the html button. The problem is that always show the polyline of facebookNorteAmerica (it goes to else) . And always recharge the map. Maybe is an amateur erro but i need help please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (continente == "Norte America" && pagina=="Baidu") {
```

by:

```
if (continente == "NorteAmerica" && pagina=="Baidu") {
```

Comment: Thank u , i didn't notice that. Howevers the map keeps recharging and i made a console.log for printing these values. This shows me NorteAmerica and Baidu , and quickly it recharges all the selects/combo box and the values are now undefined...

Comment: Replace:

<input type="submit" value="Hacer Traceroute" id="boton"/>

by:

<input type="button" value="Hacer Traceroute" id="boton"/>